# Using Facebox as a Confirm()?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog, confirm

i would like to make a modal-confirm that acts like an confirm() but looks nicer :)

im using Facebox for other things right now and would like my confirms to have the same design

http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/

Is it possible to do this in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be simple. Just put two html buttons in and when they are clicked call the facebox.close method. The only issue is that it will not be straight forward to keep the popup open if the user clicks outside the box. It will close. Maybe you can consider that a cancel event?

Comment: See [http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-facebox-dialog-modal/](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-facebox-dialog-modal/) for a way to keep the dialog from closing if the user clicks outside of it.